# Mongoose method scope in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mongoose, typescript

I have a question about the scope of the object in the callback function of Mongoose methods.
My employee has 'addresses'. When you call this 'method' it looks for the addresses in the addresses model.

Javascript:

```
employeeSchema.methods.getAddresses = function (callback) { 
  addressModel.find({ _id: { $in: this.addresses } }, function (err, obj) {
    callback(obj);
  });
};
```

I want to make everything typed and have an issue with the 'this' scope in the function.
The scope is on the object itself, however all examples show 'this'. This won't work in TypeScript as it thinks it is the main class.

TypeScript:

```
employeeSchema.methods.getAddresses = (callback) => { 
  addressModel.find({ _id: { $in: this.addresses } }, (err, obj) => {
    callback(obj);
  });
};
```

I have the same issue with validation:

```
accountSchema.path('email').validate(function (email, callback) {
  if (this.isNew || this.isModified('email')) {}
}
```

'This' is the account in the scope of the callback, but is there a way to actually pass the object to the callback?

Comment: Why not just pass in addresses into your method as a parameter? (addresses, callback)...then the caller will use "this.addresses"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to capture the lexically scoped `this`, don't use `=>`. Just use `function`.

There is a feature request to declare the meaning of `this` to be a particular type: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/229

Comment: Oke I will use function() and cast this to the typed object until then. Thanks

Comment: just a tip : prefer the term `assert` instead of `cast` as there isn't any runtime support